# Overflow-y scroll question

Tags: html, css

I have the `overflow-y:scroll` option for a div with text. However, the scroll "space" (for lack of a better word for it) appears whether the text requires scrolling or not. How do I make the appearance of the scroll "space" conditional on whether the text has a long enough height?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `scroll` to `auto`

> This value is browser and media
>   dependent, but should allow for a
>   vertical scrollbar if possible in case
>   of overflow.

http://www.css3.com/css-overflow-y/

Answer (score 2):

`scroll` means to always show the scrollbar; `auto` means to show it when necessary. Change it to `auto` instead.